# how to initialize variable default value in eclipse short cut key

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

does eclipse has shortcut key(ctrl+shift+somekey) to initialize default values of variables
e.g

```
    private Double scenarioValue;
    private Double allocatedBudget;
    //...other variables of different types

//setter n getter
```

i want this(below) because it takes alot of time to initialize each variable line by line

```
    private Double scenarioValue = 0.0;
    private Double allocatedBudget = 0.0;
    //...other variables of different types

//setter n getter
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java templates:

Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates`. Click on **New** Button.

Add the details as shown in the below picture paste `${visibility:link('public ','protected ','','private ')} ${field:link('static ','final ','transient','volatile ')} ${type:link(Object,String,byte,short,int,long,float,double,boolean,char)} ${NAME} = ${expr:link(null,'""',0,0.0,true,false)};`

into pattern text box. Click OK and exit.

In java editor type `new_` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> then choose **new_field_init** template. Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to move to other places holders and <kbd>ARROW DOWN/UP</kbd> keys to select alternative options.

[image]

Comment: Does it answers your question?